# yii2 bound two new models by id created on same action

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Have one action where i am creating few models at the same time both are extends from ActiveRecord.

```
<?php class User extends ActiveRecord 
{

}
class Balance Extends ActiveRecord
{

}
```

Controller class:

```
...
actionSignup(){
    $model = new User();
    $balance = new Balance();
    $user->balance_id = ???;
    $balance->user_id = $user->balance_id;
}
```

So till i do not save any models, i cant get id of this models! The best way to bound this models is generate some unique id in code and add specific column to database?

Comment: once you have saved  the firts model you have the related  id ..and you can rightly apply to the second ..

Comment: true! if i am saving User model before working with balance i can get id! thanks

Comment: this is the basic behaviour for activeRecord

Answer (score 0):

```
actionSignup(){
   $balance = new Balance();
   $balance>save(); 
   $model = new User();
   $user->balance_id = $balance->id;
   $user->save();
   $balance->user_id = $user->user_id;
   $balance->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.